# P2P distrubution - abstract algorithm for supervising peers

Tags: algorithm, p2p, bittorrent

I plan to make a system for distributing VM images among several stations using BitTorrent protocol. Current system looks as follows:

```
                                            |-[room with 20PCs]-
[srv_with_images]-->--[1Gbps-bottlneck]-->--|
                                            |-[2nd room with 20PCs]-
```

All the PCs at once are downloading images through the 1Gbps bottleneck every night and it takes a lot of time. We plan to use BitTorrent to speed up the distribution of images using peer-to-peer exchange between all the PCs. However there is problem - when image appears on the origin server it starts to act as a single seed from whom all peers are downloading the file simultaneously. So we again fall into the trap of the bottleneck. To speed up the distribution we need to implement (at least we think that we need) an abstract high-level algorithm that:

- Ensures the on the beggining when new image arrives only small portion of stations will be downloading the image from origin,
- When the small portion will start seeding, rest of, or another bigger portion of PCs will start peering, or they will be peering only from the PCs in class, not from origin,
- It shouldnt rely on "static" list of initial peers, as some computers may be offline during the day. We cant assume that any of the computers will always be up&running. A peer may also be turned off anytime.

Are there any specific algorithms that can help us desinging this? The most naive way would be to just keep active servers list somewhere and make some daemon that will be choosing initial peers for each torrent. But maybe there are some more elegant ways to do that kind of stuff??

Another option would be to ensure that only some peers ca download from origin, and rest of the peers do download from each other(but not from origin) - is it possible in BitTorrent protocol?

Comment: Maybe you can use [Murder](https://github.com/lg/murder), (based on BitTornado), that was developed and used by Twitter to do a similar thing.  

[Video.](http://vimeo.com/11280885)  [Blog.](https://blog.twitter.com/2010/murder-fast-datacenter-code-deploys-using-bittorrent)  [Fork.](https://github.com/russss/Herd)  [TF Article.](https://torrentfreak.com/twitter-uses-bittorrent-for-server-deployment-100210/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bittorrent no special coordination is necessary.

Peers behind the bottleneck can directly talk to each other and share the bandwidth. Using the [rarest-first](http://bittorrent.org/bittorrentecon.pdf#3) piece picking algorithm will mostly ensure that they download different pieces from the server and then share them with each other.

[LSD](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0014.html) may help to speed up lan-local discovery but it should work with a normal tracker too if there are no NAT shenanigans in play.